# How to go back to menu using case in switch case in C

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, goto

How to go back to menu using case in switch case without using GOTO command. So this is the sample:

```
while(1){
  printf("1: Basic Math\n2. Intermediate Math\n3. Advance Math");
  printf("Enter your choice: ");
  int choice;
  scanf("%d", &choice);

  switch(choice)
    int theChoices;
    case 1:
      printf("1. Add\n 2. Subtract\n3. Go back to menu");
      scanf("%d", &theChoices);

      switch (theChoices) {
         case 1:
           //calculation ...
         case 2:
           //calculation ...
         case 3:
           // Go Back to menu which is Basic math, Intermediate Math, Advance math
           // ***** I want to know how do i get back to the main menu. *****
    case 2:
    // ....
// ....................
```

So my question again is how do i get back to the menu using the case 3. When i try using the keyword break, it automatically close the program when i chose case 3. Please help.

Comment: `while ((option = show_menu_and_return_option()) != QUIT_OPTION) ... `

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it **shows no effort**. *Please try+search first*.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Switch statement not closed. Duplicate `case 2:`. You don't show how you handle `case 1:` and `case 2:` which I presume, gives defined behavior.

Comment: sorry sir but how can u say it has no effort? i try all the methods and i cant do it. i tried searching also. so i created a stackoverflow account to help me with the problem.

Comment: hi user. i got different problem. and i try to explain to the simplest like this to understand you all. :).  i want to know how do i get back to the menu using the inner switch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue;` instead. It will jump out of all `case`s and continue executing code after them, which will make the program return to the first line after `while (1)`. Don't forget to close each `case` with a `break;`.

Comment: Sir the continue button will just go to the inner switch case not the menu

Comment: @Big.D, don't forget to close _each_ `case` with a `break;`

Comment: sir i just solve my problem. instead of using nested switch case. i use else-if. then <code>continue;</code>. Thank you so much